# How to convert a python list of 3D arrays to a single 3D array of specific shape?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a list `itemlist` that has 25 `3D Arrays` with shape `(128x128x3)`

I want it to convert/merge all these values into a single common array, basically create a image out of it. I'm expecting the new shape to be `(640, 640, 3)` meaning `5 rows and 5 columns` of `(128, 128)`

I tried the following, but it is giving weird results, mostly repeating some arrays:

```
out = np.concatenate(itemlist).ravel()
out.shape ##(1228800,)

img = np.reshape(out, (640,640,3))
img.shape ## (640, 640, 3)
```

The final shape I get is correct but visually it looks like set of repeated images, is something wrong with logic?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the individual 25 images to make sure that none of them are repeated?

Comment: @clarked yes that's the first thing I did, images are absolutely fine and different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With 25  `(128,128,3)` arrays

```
out = np.concatenate(itemlist)
```

should produce a (25*128, 128,3) array

```
out = out.ravel()
```

should produce 25*128*128*3

```
out.shape ##(1228800,)
```

`(640,640,3)` matches in total number of elements, but it will not produce meaningful images.

Working backwards:

```
(5*128, 5*128,3)  => (5,128,5,128,3) => (5,5,128,128,3) => (25,128,128,3)
```

That requires a couple of reshapes, and one tranpose.

Comment: Can you share a programmatic version? I don't see where a `transpose` is being used

Comment: @JaskaranSinghPuri `transpose` or `swapaxes` used for the middle arrow, where you swap axes `1` and `2`.